# Vue.js 2. Ошибка Vue.use is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, route, router

Здравствуйте!

Начал использовать `vue-router`, но столкнулся с ошибкой:

> **Vue.use is not a function**

Гуглил, ничего не нашел (белый пояс по гуглу).

Все пути настроены правильно, модули установлены.

Почему возникает данная ошибка?

**Код**:

**index.js** (главный файл, точка входа для webpack)

```
//require modules
const Vue = require('vue');
const VueRouter = require('vue-router');

// require components
const Index = require('../public/components/Index.vue');
const Items = require('../public/components/Items.vue');
const Users = require('../public/components/Users.vue');

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Index},
    { path: '/vue', component: Users},
    { path: '/news', component: Items}
];

//Setup routes
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});

// Register components
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(Index)
});
```

**Index.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Index</h1>
        <hr>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => {return {}}
    }
</script>
```

**Ошибка**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**webpack.config.js** (возможно в конфигах не то)

```
 const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + "/public/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public",
        filename: 'build.js',
        library: 'index'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {}
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что такое `vue` в `require('vue');`? Что написано в `webpack`?

Должно быть написано.

```
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
}
```

Таким образом Вы указываете что такое `vue`.

Иначе указывайте путь.

```
require('vue/dist/vue.js');
```

Посмотрел `config`.

Меняйте как написано выше, или же используйте `import` вместо `require`.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

У Вас сейчас прописано

```
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    }
```

Вот этот файл `vue.esm.js` это модули `es6`.

Comment: прописал import

`Uncaught TypeError: VueRouter is not a constructor` ;(

Comment: Вы какой вариант выбрали?

Comment: перезапустил все, теперь 3 ошибка... 
`[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

Comment: Так сначала по `VueRouter is not a constructor`, Вы `VueRouter` тоже должны подключить через `import`.

Comment: а по 3 ошибке?)

Comment: а третей не должно быть если все делали правильно, если она все же есть, дайте ссылку на `jsfiddle` с кодом, `webpack, index.js, main.js`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vnr5cshz/

Comment: Нашел, если используете `import` , тогда везде его используете, сделайте вместо `const Index = require('../public/components/Index.vue');` это `import Index from '../public/components/Index.vue';` Ну и естественно все остальные тоже

Comment: ахаха, странно, но помогло, спасибо) Магия) Лично сам не понимаю разницу между require и импорт, но понял, что нужно почитать) Еще раз спасибо)

Comment: Если в двух словах, то `import` это модули `es6` а `require` модули `nodeJS`