# Uncaught TypeError: r.use is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Делаю с помощью webpack'a и при обновлении выдаёт ошибку:
 
`build.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: r.use is not a function`

```js
var Vue = require('vue')
var VueRouter = require('vue-router')
var About = require('./src/about.vue')
var Brand = require('./src/brand.vue')

Vue.use(VueRouter)

var router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/about', component: About},
        { path: '/brand', component: Brand}
    ]
})

new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    router: router
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}
    
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
  
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.header-wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 18px 30px 20px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  object-fit: cover;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

nav {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0 14px;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

nav a {
  margin: 0 26px 0 0;
  color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 1);
}

nav a.router-link-active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.grey {
  color: rgba(187, 187, 187, 1);
}


/* PAGES */

section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section h2 {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
}

.projects {
  background-color: rgba(242, 199, 48, 1); 
}

.brands {
  background-color: rgba(75, 192, 226, 1); 
}

.contacts {
  background-color: rgba(126, 102, 241, 1);
}


/* BLOG */

.blog {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.blog__post {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.blog__post img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  filter: brightness(70%);
}

.blog__post h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.blog__post a {
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 46px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0 48px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blog__post a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}


/* POST */

.post {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.post img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 500px;
  object-position: top center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.post h2 {
  font-size: 29px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #1f1f1f;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  max-width: 640px;
}

.post p {
  font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  max-width: 640px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue-router</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="app">
       <router-view></router-view>
   </div>
    <script src="build.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<!-- About.vue -->
<template>
    <section>
        <h2>Хоп хей лалей</h2>
    </section>
</template>
<!-- Brand.vue -->
<template>
  <section class="brands">
    <h2>Бренды</h2>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688575/vue-js-2-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-vue-use-is-not-a-function

Comment: Теперь выдаёт это: `build.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: o is not a constructor`

Comment: Читайте внимательней там все точно так же как и у вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо require from, так как require - это синтаксис Node.js, а Import/from - ES6